# How to make expanding list items like in the Mail app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, expander

I'm trying to achieve the expanding list item effect in the default Windows mail app, like below:

[image]

In this picture, I can tap the header "Charlotte Weiss" and the entire conversation drops down as an expanded list.

I've already tried using ExpanderView in the WPToolkit but it's buggy with an over extending grey bar under the header.

Does anyone know how to make this neat expanding list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just edit the style of the ExpanderView, so you can take the grey bar out? Try blend.

Comment: Did you check the details in this example? [http://michaelhubele.com/post/2013/12/30/expander-view-control](http://michaelhubele.com/post/2013/12/30/expander-view-control) there is a part about how to remove the expander bar through blend